# How many $n$ x $n$ matrices with this given property?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know how many $n$ x $n$ matrices are there containing elements that are either $1$ or $-1$, such that the product of the elements in each row and column is $-1$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  In the first column, you can pick the first $n-1$ elements any way you want, then the last element is fixed.    You need an odd number of $-1$'s in the column.  Similarly for the rest of the first $n-1$ columns.  Then the  top $n-1$ cels of the last column are fixed.  What about the lower right cell?

Comment: i understand that the (n-1)x(n-1) matrix ,excepting the last row and column , can be filled in 2^(n-1)^2 ways .
The we are left with four possibilities 
1. last column with even no. of -1 and even no. of +1
2. last column with even no. of -1 and odd no. of +1
3. last column with odd no. of -1 and even no. of +1
4. last column with odd no. of -1 and odd no. of +1

 Of these only 1. and 4. are needed
  Now how to calculate them 
   Plz help

Comment: in the points i mean "last column and row respectively"

Comment: The point is that there is only one way to fill the last row and column.  Having filled the last row and column except the bottom right, you need to convince yourself that number required by the row and column is the same.  The argument is based on the parity of the number of $-1$'s in the first block.  If you multiply all the numbers of one $(n-1) \times n$ block, you get $-1$ if $n-1$ is even and $1$ if $n-1$ is odd.  That means the last row and last column have the same parity and you have exactly one choice for the bottom right.